# Existence checking in Transaction in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactions, hibernate-annotations

I am having a similar problem to the man who posted this message in the spring forums: http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-20943.html

Basically I am writing an auto-registration feature for a website I work on. If the user exists in a third-party database we are migrating users from and not in our DB then the log in process will automatically create a user in our DB.

To do this I have to first attempt to authenticate the user on log in with the email and password. If that fails I check the third party DB and try to create the user using this information. As in the link above, It seems that this existence check followed by an insert causes the method to be marked by Hibernate as Roll-back only.

I have tried using Transactional Requires_New on the existence check to force it into a new Transaction, I was hoping this transaction would be marked as Roll-back only instead of the parent transaction, but this hasn't worked.

Can anyone advise on how to do this? The link above suggests inserting and using a duplicate key error as the check that the user already exists but this seems messy and would require significant redesign.

btw we are using Hibernate, Spring and Annotations to handle transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this that I have found is to separate the concerned sections into separate transactions. In my case I am checking if a user exists then if it doesn't but it does in my third party DB creating it. This means that if authenticate fails then the creation of the new user will not rollback but if that is required it could be separated differently so the create and authenticate methods are in the same transactional method.

```
public void login(String username, String password)
{
   User user = null;
   try {
      user = userHelper.findUserByUsername(username);
   } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
      log.warn(e);
      if (integrationLayer.checkUserExists(username))
      {
         user = userHelper.createUser(username, password);
      }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }
   }

   return userHelper.authenticate(user, password);
}

@Transactional
public User userHelper.findUserByUsername(String Username)
{
   ... find and return user ...
   ... throw user not found exception if not found ...
}

@Transactional
public User userHelper.createUser(String Username, String Password)
{
   ... create and return the new user ...
}


@Transactional
public Boolean userHelper.authenticate(String Username, String Password)
{
   ... authenticate the user ...
}

@Transactional
public Boolean integrationLayer.checkUserExists(String username)
{
   ... if the user exists in the third party DB return true ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the login method throws an exception you can fix it by 
adding a noRollbackFor option to your @Transactional attribute on the existence check method.

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor=SecuirtyExcepion.class)
public boolean authenticate(String email,String password) throws SecurityException {

}

@Transactional
public void someMethod() {
  try {
   // without noRollbackFor this would result in transaction being marked as 
   // rollback only 
    authenticate(email,password); 

  } catch(SecurityException e) {
    // create user

  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but thats not the issue. The issue is that Hibernate seems to have a quirk that if you test for somethings existence then create that object it will force a rollback.